# How can I align text to right in tinymce editor programatically

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, text-alignment

I have a web application that contains many [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) editors in side a web page. My web users want to make the text aligned to the right on pressing alt+shift. This is the code I implemented :

```
      var regularElements = ['objs', 'mats', 'procs', 'clos', 'homs'];// ids of textareas

      //  initialization of tiny mce editors from ids 
      // .........
     function handleKeyDown(e) {
        var ctrlPressed = 0;
        var altPressed = 0;
        var shiftPressed = 0;
        var evt = (e == null ? event : e);
        shiftPressed = evt.shiftKey;
        altPressed = evt.altKey;
        ctrlPressed = evt.ctrlKey;
        self.status = ""
                + "shiftKey=" + shiftPressed
                + ", altKey=" + altPressed
                + ", ctrlKey=" + ctrlPressed
        if (shiftPressed && altPressed)
        {
            $.map(regularElements, function(regularElement, i) {
                tinymce.get(regularElement).formatter.apply("alignright")
            })
        }
        return true;
    }
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        handleKeyDown(e);
    });
```

The problem is that when users press alt + shift it the editors that respond to the right alignment are the ones that are visited with the cursor (user click the content) at least one time i.e :

if just **objs** and **mats** editors are visited by the cursor in the page then **objs** and **mats** are the only editors that go to the right alignment on alt + shift . The rest do not !!

Any idea about this problem?